# What does "ii" in the first colums of the output of dpkg-query mean?

Tags: dpkg

I executed `dpkg-query -l libgtk2.0-0 libgtk-3-0` to find out the version of those packages, and I got the following output.

```
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                       Version            Architecture       Description
+++-==========================-==================-==================-==========================================================
ii  libgtk-3-0:amd64           3.22.30-1ubuntu1   amd64              GTK+ graphical user interface library
ii  libgtk2.0-0:amd64          2.24.32-1ubuntu1   amd64              GTK+ graphical user interface library
```

From `man dpkg-query` I get the following description for the first columns.

The first three columns of the output show the desired action, the package status, and errors, in that order.

```
          Desired action:
            u = Unknown
            i = Install
            h = Hold
            r = Remove
            p = Purge

          Package status:
            n = Not-installed
            c = Config-files
            H = Half-installed
            U = Unpacked
            F = Half-configured
            W = Triggers-awaiting
            t = Triggers-pending
            i = Installed

          Error flags:
            <empty> = (none)
            R = Reinst-required
```

From that description, *ii* would mean the desired action is *install* and that package is installed. It confuses me, as I would expect I don't need to take any action, if the package is already installed.

What exactly is that output telling me? Do I need to update the package, or is it already updated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you say,

> From that description, *ii* would mean the desired action is *install* but that the package is installed.

This means that the desired state for the package is “installed”, and that the current state of the package is “installed”. Since both match, no change is needed. The action column doesn’t specify actions *you* need to take, it specifies actions that the packaging system is supposed to take — in effect, this states that you’ve asked the packaging system to install these packages, directly or indirectly (*via* dependencies).

It doesn’t say anything about whether the package is up-to-date; you need to look at the output of

```
apt policy libgtk2.0-0 libgtk-3-0
```

to determine that.

`dpkg-query` only looks at the local package database in `/var/lib/dpkg/status`, so it doesn’t know about other package versions. APT is the tool which deals with package repositories and knows which versions of a package are available (and candidates for installation).

Comment: What I found confusing is that the desired action is *install* when the package is installed. The explanation is that I cannot use that command output to determine which packages need to be updated.

Comment: Yes, `dpkg-query` only queries the local package database; to know whether updates are needed, you need to look at the APT databases too, and `dpkg-query` doesn’t do that.

Comment: I was expecting that the desired action would be something else, like a space for the first column.

Comment: And that was another point of confusion for me: I thought it would query the remote databases. Thank you for clearing my confusion.

Answer (score 0):

It says in the manual extract that you include in the question, it says in the header of the output.

## Header

```
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/
```

## Manual (edited to remove distractions)

```
Desired action:
    i = Install

Package status:
    i = Installed
```

It may be that you are miss-understanding the meaning of column, in the manual. They here mean a single character. Also I think the manual has a small error. It says `desired action`, but I think it means `desired state`.

Comment: It says the meaning of two colums, separately, but it doesn't say the meaning of both the columns (i.e. what *ii* means).

Comment: The `i`s are separate. Read them as `i, i`. (no space, or other separator is needed or used, as each record in exactly one character.)

Comment: It's how I read them, but saying that the desired action is *install* is confusing, when the package is installed.